# django database model relationships

Tags: django, model

I need to work on something like grade viewing in my web app, for example, my model looks like this:

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
   subject = models.CharField(max_length= 255)

class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.Foreignkey(Student,related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enrolled_subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)


class StudentGrade(models.Model):
     student = models.Foreignkey(Student,related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     subject = models.ForeignKey(?)
     grade = ...
     period = models.ForeignKey(SchoolPeriod)
```

how can I access the `enrolled_subjects` of the `Student` object in `Student Grades` model?

should i do something like: (im not sure if I can do something like this in models.py)

```
class StudentGrade(models.Model):

    ENROLLED_SUBJECTS_CHOICES = Student.objects.filter(//some filter here)

     student = models.Foreignkey(Student,related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     subject = models.ChoiceField(choices= ENROLLED_SUBJECTS_CHOICES, default= None,)
     grade = ...
     period = models.ForeignKey(SchoolPeriod)
```

Comment: I would advise that `StudenGrade` is the "through" model of the many-to-many field. If you make `grade` a nullable field, then you can initially set that to `null` until the subject has been graded.

Comment: Im sorry I dont get it, what do you mean? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

Simply access the `ManyToMany` field from an instance, then you can apply queryset operations on it.

For example:

```py
student_subjects = StudentGrade.objects.get(student_id=1).student.enrolled_subjects.all()
```

You can also do any other operations as `filter` or `exclude`, you mainly will have access to the manager from the `enrolled_subjects`.

More examples about `ManyToMany` fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)